# Change size of image with dom minipulation

Tags: javascript

I need the image to change its size from 100px by 100px to 50px by 50px when a button is pressed.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[4].onclick= function(){
        button3('img/swim.jpg');
    };

function button3(x){
 var parent = document.getElementById("the_red_box");
 var child = document.createElement("img");
 child.src=x;
 parent.appendChild(child);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the image's width and height attributes like this:

```
function button3(x){
   var parent = document.getElementById("the_red_box");
   var child = document.createElement("img");
   child.src=x;
   child.height = 50;
   child.width = 50;
   parent.appendChild(child);
};
```